# Как удалить все скрипты родительского блока?

Tags: javascript

Как удалить все скрипты родительского блока?
Выполнить операцию нужно уже после загрузки всего DOM. Пробовал `var elem1 = document.querySelectorAll(".custom_class script");elem1.remove();`, но это не дало результата.

```html
<div class="custom_class">

<script></script>
<script></script>
<script></script>

</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: Ну кстати, скрипты не перестанут работать, если их физически удалить из страницы...

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME да, уже понял.. А как сделать, чтобы они не работали и можно ли?

Comment: вам надо знать, что делают запущенные скрипты и потом: - убрать установленные листенеры, завершить циклы, уничтожить ссылки на созданные объекты и  много еще по очистке. вопрос, зачем вам это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.querySelectorAll()` возвращает список элементов, но `elem1.remove()` обращается с ним как с одним элементом. Нужно пройтись по всему списку:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".custom_class script").forEach(element => element.remove());
```

Но, как вам уже сказали, это не гарантирует, что скрипты уже не отработают к тому времени. Вам стоит уточнить проблему, возможно, она решается совсем по-другому.